# Using (lambda args ()) prevents me from binding what's inside args

Tags: lambda, macros, scheme

The following code works:

```
(define foo (lambda (x)
  (lambda (y) (+ x y))))

((foo 2) 5) ; => 7
```

But if I want to write a macro that defines a lambda for me with any number of arguments, like so :

```
(define-syntax create-lambda
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ name args)
     (define name (lambda args
       (lambda (y) (+ x y)))))))
```

and use it like so:

```
;; create the lambda named "foo" with arguments "(x)"
(create-lambda foo (x))

((foo 2) 5) ; => Unbound variable: x
```

I get an unbound variable error.
I know *x* is not defined because it is contained inside *args* in my macro.

But if I display the result of my macro I get :

```
(define foo (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (+ x y))))
```

Which looks perfectly valid to me.

Why does defining lambda arguments as a single variable *args* prevents me from binding what's inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros in Scheme are hygenic. Thus if you pass a macro `x` it is **different** from a variable `x` in the macro since they came from different scopes. A practical examnple where this is useful is the `swap!` macro:

```
(define-syntax swap! 
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ from to) 
     (let ((tmp from))
       (set! from to)
       (set! to tmp)))))

(define tmp 10)
(define test 20)
(swap! tmp test)
(list tmp test) ; ==> (20 10)
```

A naive version of a macro expander might leak the macros used variable `tmp` and end up as `(20 20)`, but instead the expansion of `(swap! tmp test)` might look something like this:

```
 (let ((tmp$1 tmp))
   (set! tmp test)
   (set! test tmp$1)))))
```

I just appended $1 to the symbols created by the macro. It might be that it ends up looking the same, but for the Scheme implementation they are different variables as if they had different names. A macro should never rely on not getting conflicting symbols since programmers tend to reuse the same ones. You code would look like:

```
(define name 
  (lambda (x)
    (lambda (y$1) (+ x$1 $1)))))))
```

And here it is obvious `x$1` is unbound and does not exist. Anyway you would rather be interested in a macro where both the names and the body comes as input, like:

```
(define-syntax lambda-arity1
  (syntax-rules ()
    ; one argument
    ((_ (arg) body ...) 
     (lambda (arg) body ...))
    ; two or more arguments
    ((_ (arg arg2 ...) body ...) 
     (lambda (arg) (lambda-arity1 (arg2 ...) body ...)))))


(lambda-arity1 (a b c d) (+ a b c d))
; == (lambda (a) (lambda (b) (lambda (c) (lambda (d) (+ a b c d)))))
```

Since the names also come from the user `a` in the list is the same as `a` in the body and it works perfectly. `(((lambda-arity1 (a b) (+ a b) 1) 2) ; ==> 3`

Comment: If I understand well, this is what makes Scheme a "lexical scoped" language. Thanks for your anwser and your examples!

Comment: @Jérôme Even the compile time code is lexically scoped in Scheme. In CL, which also is a lexically scoped language, the macro system does not provide hygiene so it requires programmers to use packages or `gensym` to not collide variables.